# Python 3.5 -- Save & Load file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to save & load from a menu list in Python 3.5 and receive a ValueError.

part of my code:

```
   elif menuItem == 5:
        filename = input("Filename to save: ")
        outFile = open(filename, "wt")
        for name, jersey, phone in players.items():
            outFile.write(name + "," + jersey + "," + phone + "\n")
        print("Data saved.")
        outFile.close()
    elif menuItem == 6:
        filename = input("Filename to load: ")
        inFile = open(filename, "rt")
        print("Loading data...")
        while True:
            inLine = inFile.readline()
            if not inLine:
                break
            inLine = inLine[:-1]
            name, jersey, phone = inLine.split(",")
            players[name] = (name, jersey, phone)
        print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
        inFile.close()
```

The error I get:

line 88, in Player
    for name, jersey, phone in players.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)

I am not sure how it is only unpacking 2. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

> > > Edit: More of the code to shed light:

```
print(">>> Welcome to the Team Roster Manager <<<")
players = {}
menuItem = 0
print_menu()
while menuItem != 9:
    print("\n")
    menuItem = int(input("Please choose a number."))
    print("\n")

    if menuItem == 1:
        print_roster()
    elif menuItem == 2:
        name = input("Add a player's Name: ")
        jerseyNo = input("Jersey number: ")
        phone = input("Telephone number: ")
        players[name] = (name, jerseyNo, phone)
        print()
    elif menuItem == 3:
        name = input("What name would you like to remove? ")
        if name in players:
            del players[name]
            print(name, "has been removed.")
            print()
        else:
            print("Sorry", name, "was not found!")
            print()
    elif menuItem == 4:
        name = input("What name would you like to change? ")
        if name in players:
            name = input("What is the new name? ")
            print("***", name, "has been changed.")
            print()
        else:
            print("***Sorry", name, "was not found!")
            print()
    elif menuItem == 5:
        filename = input("Filename to save: ")
        outFile = open(filename, "wt")
        for name, jersey, phone in players.items():
            outFile.write(name + "," + jersey + "," + phone + "\n")
        print("Data saved.")
        outFile.close()
    elif menuItem == 6:
        filename = input("Filename to load: ")
        inFile = open(filename, "rt")
        print("Loading data...")
        while True:
            inLine = inFile.readline()
            if not inLine:
                break
            inLine = inLine[:-1]
            name, jersey, phone = inLine.split(",")
            players[name] = (name, jersey, phone)
        print("Data Loaded Successfully.")
        inFile.close()
    elif menuItem == 9:
        print("Exiting program...")
```

Comment: Dictionaries are made up of keys and values.  When you call `.items()`, you get a series of two-tuples, each containing one key and one value.  Since you haven't shown us what this `players` object is supposed to be, we're not going to be able to figure out what you actually meant to do instead.

Comment: @Kevin the players object refers to the library I set up earlier in the code.  players = {}  menuItem = 0  print_menu()